# Validating Time Format with Regular Expression

Tags: javascript

I have to create a combination stopwatch and countdown timer and validate the time format (00:00:00) of the countdown with a regular expression. I tried using var regex = /^\d{0-2}:\d{0-2}:\d{0-2}$/; but keeps coming up as invalid. Not sure if the regex code is wrong or I have it in the wrong place? Also supposed to be showing the event output in a div area below but everything's coming up as "undefined" so far. Totally confused and would appreciate any ideas. Thanks so much!

```js
   // start stopwatch function and declare variables
        var hundr = 10;
        var minutes = 0;
        var seconds = 0;
        var stopwatch = 0;

    // begin stopwatch
       function startStopwatch(){
       "use strict";
        stopwatch = setInterval('setUp()', 100); 
       }
          

    // function to show if the timer reaches 60 seconds, display an alert that says "Time up!" Otherwise, continue incrementing hundredths/seconds
    function setUp(){
    var setTime = document.getElementById('output');
        hundr+=10;
        if (hundr == 100) {
        seconds++;
        hundr = 0;
        }
        if (seconds == 60) {
        minutes++;
        seconds = 0;
        setTime.innerHTML = "Time up!";
        clearInterval(stopwatch);
        return;
}

        // if/else statement to display stopwatch - if number of seconds/minutes are less than 10, display a zero.
        if(seconds < 10){
        setTime.innerHTML = '0' + minutes + ':0' + seconds + ':' + hundr;
        } else {
        setTime.innerHTML = '0' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ':' + hundr;
        } 
        if(hundr < 10) {
        setTime.innerHTML = '0' + minutes + ':0' + seconds + ':0' + hundr;
       } else {
        setTime.innerHTML = '0' + minutes + ':0' + seconds + ':' + hundr;
    }}
       

    // start countdown function and declare variables
        var ms = 99;
        var mins = 0;
        var secs = 60;
        var countdown = 0;

    function startCountdown(){
        "use strict";        
        countdown = setInterval('incrTimer()', 10);
        }

    function incrTimer(){
        "use strict";

    var regMatch = document.getElementById("output").value;
    var regex = /^\d{0-2}:\d{0-2}:\d{0-2}$/;    
        if (regex.test(regMatch)) { 
           document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = "valid";
        } else {
           document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = "invalid - please check your code";
        }
        var setCountd = document.getElementById('output');
        ms--;
        if (ms == -1) {
        secs--;
        ms = 99;
        } 
        if(secs == -1){
        min--;
        secs = 59;
        setCountd.innerHTML = "Time up!";
        clearInterval(countdown);
        alert('Time up');
        return;
    }

        // if/else statement to display countdown - if number of seconds/minutes are less than 10, display a zero in front of number.
        if(secs > 10){
        setCountd.innerHTML = '0' + mins + ':' + secs + ':' + ms;
        } else {
        setCountd.innerHTML = '0' + mins + ':' + secs + ':' + ms;
        } 
        if(ms < 10) {
        setCountd.innerHTML = '0' + mins + ':' + secs + ':0' + ms;
       } else {
        setCountd.innerHTML = '0' + mins + ':' + secs + ':' + ms;
    }}

       // end function incrTimer()


function stopTimer() { // pauses the output for both the stopwatch and the countdown timer
    clearTimeout(stopwatch);
    clearTimeout(countdown);
    } // end function stopTimer()

function clearOutput() { // clear output and restore div area
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
    } // end function clearOutput
```

```css
#output{
    width:300px;
    height:25px;
    background-color: #e4e3db;
    border:1px solid #c3c4bc;

}

span {
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    background-color: #00FFFF;
}




h2 {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #799b3d;
}

h4 {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #1f8da8;
}

#debug {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 620px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: small;
    color: blue;
    background-color: #FFFF99;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Final</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="final.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="take7.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
<h2>Stopwatch or Countdown Timer</h2>
 <div id="output" ></div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>


    <span id="stopwatch_output" onclick="startStopwatch()">Stopwatch</span>
    <span id="countdown_output" onclick="startCountdown()">Countdown</span>  
    <span id="timerstop" onclick="stopTimer()">STOP</span>
    <span id="resettimer" onclick="clearOutput()">RESET</span>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><span id="debugOnOff" style="visibility:visible">Debug on/off</span>
       <span id="hideDebug" style="visibility:visible">Hide Debug</span>
<div id="debug"><p id="firstP">This space is reserved for event output information.</p></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is a typical value of `regMatch`? There are a lot of online regex testers [like this one](https://regex101.com/) where you can feed in your regex and sample text, and have it explain what is going on.

Comment: Well, this is what confuses me since the value isn't anything a user types in, it's just supposed to validate that I used the 00:00:00 format, so I used "output" as the value for regMatch. Not even sure that's right...

Comment: Thank you for the link Ken Y-N, I will check this out!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check timer value with and without leading zero you can use this regex:

```
([0-9]+):([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])
```

Returns true for `01:1:01` or `1:1:1` but not for `1::1` or `::`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a minor typo:

```
var regex = /^\d{0-2}:\d{0-2}:\d{0-2}$/;
```

To specify a match for zero to two digits (would one or two be better?) you use a comma as a separator:

```
var regex = /^\d{0,2}:\d{0,2}:\d{0,2}$/;
```

It's a typo that's easy to overlook!

Comment: Your regex will return true even for `::`

Comment: Indeed, that's why I said "would one or two be better?"!

Comment: Thanks to you both for the formatting help!! I think the problem might be where I have it placed in the code...I added it under the startCountdown() function thinking it would work when the user hits the countdown button, but its still coming up as invalid. Guess I'll keep experimenting. Appreciate the help!

Comment: I understood it as a question, so I answered. btw your regex is also useful, depends on requirements :)